# How to encode string and send over socket without the "b" character in the byte string

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, request

I'm starting to play around with Python sockets and I found the following example online for sending and receiving data to a web URL:

```
import socket
import sys

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
    print("Failed to create socket")
    sys.exit()

print("Socket created")

host = input("Enter URL here: ")
port = 80

try:
    remoteIP = socket.gethostbyname(host)
except socket.gaierror:
    print("Host name could not be resolved")
    sys.exit()

s.connect((remoteIP, port))

print("Socket connected to " + host + " on IP " + remoteIP)

message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
messagebytes = str.encode(message)

try:
    s.sendall(messagebytes)
except socket.error:
    print("Send failed")
    sys.exit()

print("Message sent successfully")

reply = s.recv(4096)

print(reply)
```

Now the issue is whenever I run this code, I get the following output:

> b'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nProxy-Connection: close\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: 1229\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nRequest Error\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n**My Internet Access**
> \r\n\r\n--\r\n\r\n\r\n
>
> > \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nRequest Error\r\n\r\n
> > \r\n\r\n
> > \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nYour request could not be processed. Request could not be handled\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nThis could be caused by a misconfiguration, or possibly a malformed request.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
> > \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nFor assistance, please log a call with the helpdesk.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
>
> \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n

\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n'

My only guess for this outcome is that the message being sent is sent as `b"  therefore GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"` and that `b` c, therefore, making it an invalid request. I tried decoding it as well and it didn't help as I get the exact same outcome as when I do not decode it.

If that is the case how can I fix this?

Comment: You have to .decode("encoding eg. UTF-8") response. But you have to know or gues encoding.

Comment: I tried decoding it, and I still got the same outcome. Let me just add that to the question details.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I'm aware of what the 'b' character does in front of a string. And I know that with bytes on Python it prints the byte string with the 'b' character in front of it, which is what I'm assuming is causing the bad request.

Comment: Please say what error do you recive, when you decode it?

Comment: Edited my question. It just gives the exact same outcome as posted in the question

Comment: For learning sockets see this free course: https://www.cybrary.it/course/python/ it is not as hard as it sounds. You can skip to Packet Analyser lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v tried decode the response and I made it.

```
>>> a=b'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-
8\r\nProxy-Connection: close\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: 1229\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nRequest Error\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r
\n\r\n\r\n\r\nMy Internet Access\r\n\r\n--\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r
\n\r\n\r\n\r\nRequest Error\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nYour request could no
t be processed. Request could not be handled\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nThis could be caused by a mi
sconfiguration, or possibly a malformed request.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nFor assistance,
please log a call with the helpdesk.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n'
>>> a.decode('UTF-8')
'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nPr
oxy-Connection: close\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: 1229\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nRequest Error\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\
r\n\r\nMy Internet Access\r\n\r\n--\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\
r\n\r\nRequest Error\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nYour request could not be pr
ocessed. Request could not be handled\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nThis could be caused by a misconfig
uration, or possibly a malformed request.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nFor assistance, please
log a call with the helpdesk.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n'
```

But problem with your code is in request headers. If you want to get some content of page, you can use `urllib.request` package.
First you need some setup:

```
import urllib.request as req


class Fetch:
    """
    Class responsible for getting code of page at specified url
    """

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.data = None
        self.obj = None
        self.headers = None
        self.encoding = None

    def fetch_file(self):
        """
        :return: str contents of a website
            Returns string data form an url
        """

        self.obj = req.urlopen(self.url)
        self.encoding = self.obj.headers['content-type'].split('charset=')[-1]
        self.data = self.obj.read().decode(self.encoding)
        return self.data
```

Then you import Fetch class and pass desired url to init object. At the end you call fetch_file() it returns encoded response if in response headers is charset specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this when sending:

```
message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"

s.sendall(messagebytes.encode())
```

And while receiving:

```
reply = s.recv(4096)

print(reply.decode())
```

Comment: Would you care to explain this code you have posted?

Comment: Actually, the idea is simple: Whatever you are sending out, if it is in a string form, you can simply use .encode() method for encoding in ascii.
And later on, after receiving that message, you need to use .decode() method for the encoded message to convert it back into simple string form. Otherwise it prints an additional 'b' at the beginning of the message, if printed directly, which the original question was for.