# Truncated text when using HtmlUnit to save complete page

Tags: java, python, web-crawler

I've tried to save the complete page using Java or Python and I also have tried selenium and wget.
Finally I've chosen HtmlUnit because it can be easily achieved by using save().

My page is getting truncated, the Chinese characters show as "?".
Is there any way to change the encoding? Or there have any other tools to save the complete page?

My code:

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);

    try {
        HtmlPage htmlPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.fulijr.com/");
        File file = new File("fulijr.html");
        htmlPage.save(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="????,????????,??????P2P????"/>
        <meta name="description" content="??????????P2P???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????P2P???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????"/>
        ...
```

Comment: You have to do something like this (like in Fetch class): https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493023/4392611 and before saving read encoding declaration, otherwise it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the current version of HtmlUnit (version 2.33). Have fixed this; will inform on https://twitter.com/HtmlUnit if a new snapshot build is available.

Comment: Thanks,  I have tried build 2.34-SNAPSHOT and it's work.

Comment: When is the release for this 2.34 coming out?